# How to wrap visual program with term?

Tags: ansi-term, term

I have installed [visidata](https://www.visidata.org/) and am trying to integrate into my Emacs workflow through term-mode. As a proof of concept, I'm trying to successfully explore the [mtcars](https://gist.github.com/seankross/a412dfbd88b3db70b74b) data set as it would work when started `*ansi-term*`. That's not good enough for me since I would like to write additional functionality to integrate this into another program in Emacs (ESS).

```
(term-ansi-make-term "*vd<mtcars>*" "vd" nil "/path/to/mtcars.csv")
```

When I run this the vd table appears in the *vd* buffer, but none of the keybindings actually work. What am I missing?

Ideally, when I am done interactively exploring the data in vd, I could press `q` repeatedly until all "sheets" exit and automatically close the buffer when the process ends. Is there some existing emacs functionality which would make this possible?

Comment: Maybe I can kill the buffer automatically using something like `(let ((livingp (process-live-p (get-buffer-process (get-buffer "*vd<mtcars>*"))))) (when (not livingp) (kill-buffer "*vd<mtcars>*"))`? This of course doesn't handle the problem of getting the buffer to show reliably in the first place.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info